# I want to catch the argument whose checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events

I want to catch the argument whose checkbox is checked but if my tr is under form then he is giving me the whole tr. Please help me.
Here is my **jQuery code:**

```
 $('#form').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.checkbox').is(':checked')){
            var selector = $(this).closest("tr")//get closest tr
            console.log(selector)
      //get select valus
        var id = selector.attr('data-id');
            alert(id);
        var package_name = selector.find('.visa_type').val();
        var prcs_type_price = selector.find("select[name=processing_type]").val();
        var processing_type = selector.find("select[name=processing_type] option:selected").text();
        var total = selector.find(".package_price").text(prcs_type_price).val()
            var date = selector.find('.travel_date').val();
    }
)};
```

Comment: Please 1. do not tag irrelevant tags and 2. use the `[<>]` snippet editor to add relevant HTML and CSS

Comment: `var total = selector.find(".package_price").text(prcs_type_price).val()` does not look right either

Comment: it shows me this error Uncaught TypeError: $(...).forEach is not a function

Comment: Sorry. each, not forEach

Comment: @mplungjan If you fix the tags - do all of them!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run .each over the checked ones

```js
$('#form').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.checkbox:checked',this).each(function() {
      const $row = $(this).closest("tr"); 
      const id = $row.id;
      const package_name = $row.find('.visa_type').val();
    })
```

You CAN do this `.on("input"` and have the fields update on any change